# Trajectory of an arrow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm making a simulation of a flying arrow, but it doesn't look very natural.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The anchor of the arrow movieclip is at the front of the arrow like you can see, but if I replace it to the middle, it still doesn't look perfect, does anyone have any experience with something like this?

Here's my code too:

```
//...
//'math' isn't the default 'Math' class, it calculates some physics stuff.

private function updateArrow()
        {
            var y0:Number = 50;
            var v:Number = 100;
            var angle:Number = math.getRadians(45);

            if(!arrowstartposition)
            {
                arrowstartposition = activearrow.x;
                arrowdistance = math.calcDistance(y0,v,angle);
            }

            var currentdistance:Number = Math.abs(activearrow.x - arrowstart);

            if(currentdistance <= arrowdistance)
            {
                var currentvelocity:Number = math.calcVelocity(currentdistance, v, angle);
                var addvalue:int = 1; //Math.round(currentvelocity / 4);

                activearrow.x += addvalue;
                currentdistance += addvalue;

                var arrowheight:Number = math.calcHeight(currentdistance,y0,v,angle);
                var vx:Number = v * Math.cos(angle);
                var vy:Number = - (v * Math.sin(angle) - 9.81 * (currentdistance / arrowdistance) * math.calcTimeOfFlight(y0, v, angle));
                var currentangle:Number = Math.atan2(vy,vx);

                activearrow.y = y0 - arrowheight;
                activearrow.rotation = math.getDegrees(currentangle);
            }
            else
            {
                arrowstart = undefined;
                arrowdistance = undefined;
                activearrow = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: One problem is that your trajectory is too parabolic. The correct trajectory is better modeled by using vectors for each part of the arrow; the head and hardwood will experience gravity and little wind resistance, the effect of the shaft is largely negligible, and the fletching will experience some amount of lift. So a simple parabola based on 9.81 will not model it correctly. Also, you have drag, which is a continuous function of the velocity.

Comment: @drharris but the shape of the curve will *look* most natural if it is a perfect parabola, even if it's not the most physically accurate.

Comment: True of course, but he claimed to be making a simulation. Simulations typically put accuracy above effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think your center of gravity is off.  The arrowhead isn't going to be where the center of the gravity is for the arrow.  Otherwise it wouldn't fly very well.  The center of gravity of the arrow will be tangential to the parabola of flight.  So it will rotate around that center of gravity.  Try moving it more towards the center of the arrow and it will start to look more natural.  If you still have trouble.  Try throwing just a stone and get that looking natural.  Then add back in the arrow.  If it looks good as a stone, then looks bad as an arrow you know the motion is correct, but arrow is off.

Comment: I've changed it to a 'stone', and it seems that there's something wrong with the speed. Do you add a constant value each frame, so the horizontal axe will be represent time units, or do you add a value based on the current velocity. (like `currentvelocity / 4`)

Comment: For more natural movement you'll want to accelerate and decelerate.  Instead of using a constant velocity you'll want to change it over time.  As the arrow moves up it's affected by gravity more and more until it reaches the height of the parabola where it changes direction and falls back to earth.  So out of the gate you'll want a Vy0 of something very fast, at each frame you'll add -9.81 m/s^2 / frame rate since frame rate units are frames/s.  The Horizontal axis will be X direction and the vertical axis will be Y direction. -9.81 will affect the Y direction stopping when it hits a solid obj

Comment: Vy = Vy0;  // initial velocity
Vx = Vx0;  // these would also be calculated from some power * sin/cos theta where theta is the starting angle
while( stillInAir ) {
  Vy = Vy - 9.8 / frameRate;
  Vx = Vx + windSpeed;
}